# Meteor: Hot Code Push Causing App to Crash

Tags: cordova, meteor, updates, auto-update, meteor-cordova

We have a Meteor application that houses a web application and a mobile application.  The web application is built in the standard Meteor fashion (`both`, `client`, `server`, etc.).  The mobile application is included as a package.  The `package.js` for the mobile app only loads client-side files in the `web.cordova` context.

We are having issues with pushing new updates to the mobile app.  The mobile app has been built using meteor, deployed via Apple Enterprise and a direct download of an Android `*.apk` file.

Installs go off without a hitch.  When we make updates to either the app's client or the main app's server code, however, the app often crashes (white screen) or misbehaves in other ways.

Are others having issues here?  Does Meteor hot code push work reliably for a built and bundled app that sits in a package?  We really need to be able to push updates to our users without them having to re-download the app.  We understand we could use the techniques and packages mentioned [here](http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-hot-code-push) to mitigate the disruption caused by hot code pushes, but are not able to determine whether or not this will work for a situation where we are making updates to the code intended for cordova, not the client.

Our live server also does not include the `android` and `ios` platforms due to deployment restrictions.  Are those required for cordova updates to be properly pushed to connected iOS/Android apps?

Answer (score 1):

We were in the same situation and we were only developing iOS apps with a plan to later supporting Android. Our experience has been that cross platform development tools, especially Cordova were becoming more and more of a nightmare. It was like going backward in time to the days we had to support multiple browsers and versions. I think you'll start to notice that more and more cross platform tools are getting abandoned by developers, and/or they are even getting passed around from who owns the product.

Beyond the huge costs due to very low productivity, I share this link with you rather than trying to express the reasons for our switching to developing native iOS apps and native Android apps, instead of using any cross platform tools.

Here you go: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3851515

Comment: I suppose moving to native applications is a solution of sorts, but out of scope for us in the near term.